# Laplace transform signal

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Is this correct ?

$$x(t)= \begin{cases} e^{-5t}, & 0≤t<5 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

\begin{align}
L[x(t)] &=\int_{-\infty}^∞x(t)e^{-st}dt \\
&=\int_{0}^5e^{-5t}e^{-st} dt \\
&=\int_{0}^5e^{-(5+s)t}dt \\
&=\left[\frac{-1}{5+s}∙e^{-(5+s)t} \right]_{0}^{5} \\
&={-1\over 5+s}\left(e^{-(5+s)5}-e^{0}\right) \\
&={-1\over 5+s}\left(e^{-(5+s)5}-e^{0}\right) \\
&={-1\over 5+s}\left(e^{-(5+s)5}-1\right) \\
&={1\over 5+s}\left(1-e^{-(5+s)5}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: yes good job   ..